# strtotime(); Problems with posted data

Tags: php, strtotime

I am posting a time value from one page to another using html input type *time*. The posted value is displaying correctly but it doesn't show any output after applying strtotime().

Here is my HTML code

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="time" name="usr_time1">
    <input type="time" name="usr_time2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and this is my php code

```
<?php
echo $t1= $_POST['usr_time1']."<br>";
echo $t2= $_POST['usr_time2']."<br>";
echo $timestamp = strtotime($t1);
```

What is wrong here..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding `<br>` to your time, just remove it or add it later.

```
<?php
$t1= $_POST['usr_time1'];
$t2= $_POST['usr_time2'];
echo $t1."<br>";
echo $t2."<br>";
echo $timestamp = strtotime($t1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are also adding `<br>` to `$t1`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<br>` appended

```
<?php
echo $t1= $_POST['usr_time1'];
echo $t2= $_POST['usr_time2'];
echo $timestamp = strtotime($t1);
```